# iPhone Development - NSString to floatValue

Tags: iphone, nsstring, calculator

Hey
I'm creating a calculator as an iphone app.

I have a UITextfield where the user enters his input
EX:   3+4-48*23+43

and i have a UILabel that will display the result after pressing on "calculate button".

CODE:

```
float result;
NSString *textFieldValue= self.myTextField.text;  
// i need a line of code to calculate the values in the string and convert it to     floatValue
result=[textFieldValue  floatValue];
[self.myLabel.text stringWithFormat:@"%f",result];
```

Comment: So you're essentially asking how you can write a numeric expression parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are looking for ready made open source resources start here: http://apptree.net/parser.htm

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into [Reverse Polish Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). [Here is the first example](http://www.math.bas.bg/bantchev/place/rpn/rpn.objc.html) I cam across in a google search for Objective-C.